# Sublime Text 2: No module named __future__

Tags: 12.10, sublime-text

I lost track of how many times I've been bumping into this issue with different OSes. Now with Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Okay, the problem is on startup of Sublime Text an error message saying among other things `No module named __future__` appears and it's impossible to launch the application. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 requires a Python 2.6 library. This problem is caused by it being unable to find it. It's possible to fix this by placing the contents of a `Lib` folder from a python distribution archive downloaded [from here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/) into a `lib/python2.6` folder of Sublime Text 2 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Nikita's answer didn't work for me, but I noticed that I only had problems when using symlinks to Sublime Text and not when using the "real" path to the executable. Then I tested with an alias; lo and behold, it works.

Add one of these to your `alias` or `rc` file (usually, `bash_rc` tests if `.bash_aliases` exists and automatically includes it)

```
alias subl="/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text -w"

alias sublime="/opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text -w"
```

However, if you want to use it in something that uses another shell, particularly Bourne shell, you'll have to exchange the backslashes and wrap the executable in single quotes; example from .muttrc:

```
set editor = "'/opt/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text' -w"    # Use Sublime Text 2 to compose email.
```